# How do I control bar colors in plot_ly with reactive data in shiny

Tags: r, plotly, shiny

I am creating an R shiny dashboard and data is being filtered. Reactive data is processed. When different selections are made, the colors in the bar chart change and aren't consistent. The colors signify Good, Neutral, Bad, and not available so the order matters. Full shiny app is at: https://stoltzmaniac.shinyapps.io/medicare_data/ and the code is at: https://github.com/stoltzmaniac/Medicare/tree/master/shinyApp (both server.R and ui.R) Plotly portion looks like:

```
plot_ly(df_filtered, x = ~Score, y = ~Hospital.Name, 
        type = "bar", color = ~Compared.to.National, colors = FORMAT_CHART_COLOR_LIST, 
        hoverinfo = 'text', text = ~paste('State: ', State, 
                                          '<br> City: ', City,
                                          '<br> Score: ', Score))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plotly help says it [here](https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/#custom-color-scales) (scroll down a bit). Define a named color vector:

```
global_colors <- setNames(rainbow(nrow(data)), data$brand) # this maps brand to color
```

I suppose your data is

```
data <- head(mtcars)
data$brand <- rownames(data)
```

Then, the plot is created as

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~brand, y = ~hp, type = "bar", color = ~brand, colors = globalcolors)
```

(Note there's no `~` before `globalcolors` because that's the global color vector)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks @shosaco , I placed `global_colors` as the `reactiveVal` like you mentioned within the global.R file. However, when I used it within plot_ly I received this error: "Error: no applicable method for 'toPaletteFunc' applied to an object of class "AsIs" and I have tried several methods to fix but can't seem to get it to work. The rest of the app still works

Comment: So, just to be clear, with my prior syntax this would be it?    `global_colors <- reactiveVal(setNames(rainbow(nrow(df)), df$Compared.to.National))`   And then the:  `df_filtered$color <- global_colors()[df_filtered$Compared.to.National]`  Then finally:     
`plot_ly(df_filtered, x = ~Score, y = ~Hospital.Name, 
        type = "bar", color = ~Compared.to.National, colors = ~I(color), 
        hoverinfo =`
  Correct?

Comment: try `color = ~I(color)` (and no `colors` argument, which only tells plotly which variable it should use to determine different colors. You already did that by filling the color column).

Comment: Thanks, seems like it may be one step closer... however, now it all simply shows up as one color (bright red in my case) - `plot_ly(df_filtered, x = ~Score, y = ~Hospital.Name, type = "bar", color = ~I(color)` - The legend also disappears when I do that. If I was able to setup the `Compared.to.National` and create a new column right out of the gate with an exact color column `color` would that work and there's perhaps just a way to change the legend text? Obviously, not a great solution but could get the job done

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the plotly helpt says it very clear, I updated my answer accordingly (is was even a bit easier)