# How do I set fixed line colors for each data category in ggplotly with reactive data in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I am working on a shiny app, which would allow to plot certain type of genomic data.

The app is intended to accept dataframes with fixed column names but of various length. I want that app to display distribution plots of certain genes of interests.

In case of dropdown menu for selecting certain genes, the selectizeInput() on server side is used to increase speed (in real life dataframes there are thousands of unique gene labels).

My app works fine - in terms that it plots distributions of interest. However, in case if only certain conditions are meant to be plotted, the colors of the lines are different than the colors representing given sample if they are plotted together. Also, if some groups are clicked out in the plot area (while ignoring the sidebar menu options for selecting certain conditions) the colors of lines are different than those produced while the dropdown and checkbox are used.

This might be confusing for some users, so I'd like to avoid this.

My question is: how can I prevent switching the colors of the lines in the described situation?

I have found a following thread regarding plot_ly: [How do I control bar colors in plot_ly with reactive data in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483603/how-do-i-control-bar-colors-in-plot-ly-with-reactive-data-in-shiny)

However, I am using ggplotly (I have to because my real app uses some plotting functions which require this), so the above is not applicable.

Here is my shiny app with predefined dummy data:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

group <- c(rep("MINUS", 40), rep("PLUS", 40))
sample <- c(rep("KO1",20),rep("KO2",20), rep("WT1",20), rep("WT2",20))
gene <- c(rep("ABC",4),rep("DEF",7), rep("XYZ",9), rep("ABC",6),
          rep("XYZ",3),rep("DEF",11),rep("ABC",8),rep("DEF",5),
          rep("XYZ",7), rep("ABC",7),rep("XYZ",6),rep("DEF",7))
length <- c(5.42, 5.92, 4.73, 5.64, 5.57, 6.22, 5.61, 6.95, 5.28, 3.13,
            4.66, 5.06, 4.83, 7.29, 6.92, 5.89, 8.33, 6.40, 6.10, 5.50,
            5.32, 5.02, 3.29, 3.57, 2.79, 4.14, 3.85, 3.95, 3.91, 5.34,
            4.52, 4.15, 6.19, 4.32, 1.19, 4.67, 3.71, 4.34, 2.93, 2.63,
            8.35, 8.07, 6.54, 9.23, 8.01, 8.05, 7.84, 7.62, 9.15, 7.03,
            7.93, 7.18, 9.76, 5.89, 7.66, 8.34, 7.55, 6.76, 7.28, 8.98,
            7.42, 7.97, 5.86, 6.61, 6.58, 7.42, 5.77, 5.99, 8.11, 8.65,
            7.13, 6.42, 7.52, 7.87, 4.66, 7.76, 6.46, 6.21, 8.18, 7.73)


data <- data.frame(group, sample, gene, length)



# label genes for dropdown menu
gene_labels <- sort(unique(data$gene))

# custom function for plotting data
plot_distr <- function(data, groupby=NA){
  plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(data,ggplot2::aes(x=length,color=!!rlang::sym(groupby)))+
    ggplot2::geom_line(stat="density",size=1,ggplot2::aes(y=..ndensity..))
  return(plot)
}


# Define ui logic ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyWidgets::useShinydashboard(),
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Test application"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width=2,
      # SELECTIZEINPUT FOR GENE SELECTION
      shiny::selectizeInput(
        inputId = "list_of_genes",
        label = "Select gene:",
        choices = NULL
      ), #selectizeInput
      selectInput(
        inputId = "selected_grouping_variable",
        label = "Select grouping variable:",
        choices = c(
          "sample" = "sample",
          "condition (group)" = "group")),
      checkboxInput("show_comment",label = "Display comments?",value = FALSE),
      uiOutput("level"),
      # selectInput(
      #   inputId = "selected_grouping_variable_level",
      #   label = "Select certain condition:",
      #   choices = c(unique(data$sample))),#this is only a placeholder with hardcode
      checkboxInput("show_comment2",label = "Plot only selected condition?",value = FALSE)

    ),
    mainPanel(
      box(
        width=8,
        plotlyOutput("distribution_plot", height = "450px"),
        div(id = "text_div",
            textOutput("textofinterest"),
            style="text-align: justify;")

      ),
  
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({print(input$show_comment2)})
  #select var to plot
  selected_variable_plot <- reactive({
    selected_grouping_variable <- switch(input$selected_grouping_variable,
                                         sample = "sample",
                                         group = "group")
  })

  output$level <- renderUI({
    req(input$selected_grouping_variable)
    choices <- as.list(unique(data[[input$selected_grouping_variable]]))
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_grouping_variable_level',
                label = 'Select certain condition:',
                choices = choices, selected=choices[[1]], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`style` = "btn-success"))
  })

  selected_variable_capt <- shiny::reactive({
    selected_variable_2 <- switch(input$selected_grouping_variable,
                                  sample = "sample",
                                  group = "group")
  })

  # SELECTIZE INPUT - SERVER SIDE
  shiny::updateSelectizeInput(
    inputId = 'list_of_genes',
    label = 'Select gene of interest:',
    choices = unique(gene_labels),
    server=TRUE,
    options = list(maxOptions = length(gene_labels))
  )

  shiny::observe({print(input$list_of_genes)})

  filtered_data <- shiny::reactive({
    data %>% dplyr::filter(gene==as.character(input$list_of_genes))
  })

  mydata <- reactive({
    req(input$selected_grouping_variable_level)
    if (input$show_comment2){
      df <- filtered_data() %>% mutate(newvar = !!sym(input$selected_grouping_variable)) %>%
        dplyr::filter(newvar %in% input$selected_grouping_variable_level) %>%
        select(-newvar)
    }else df <- filtered_data()
    df
  })

  # plot
  output$distribution_plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(mydata(),selected_variable_plot())
    distr_plot <- plot_distr(data = mydata(), groupby = selected_variable_plot())
    distr_plot <- ggplotly(distr_plot)
    return(distr_plot)
  })

  # caption
  whichcaption <- reactive(input$selected_grouping_variable)

  which_caption <- reactive({
    if (whichcaption()=="sample") {
      caption1 <- "I'm a Barbie girl, in a Barbie world"
    } else {
      caption2 <- "Life in plastic is fantastic!"
    }
  })

  # display comments or do not
  observe({
    toggle(id = "text_div", condition = input$show_comment)
    output$textofinterest <- renderText({
      which_caption()
    })
  })

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I recognize this is not ideal. Here's one solution where you have to manually update the plotly object. Not sure how time consuming this is for a large data set. I first set up a named vector to hold the color for each sample.

```
global_colors = setNames(c("red","purple","blue","green"),unique(data$sample))

# > global_colors
#     KO1      KO2      WT1      WT2 
#   "red" "purple"   "blue"  "green"
```

Next in the `#plot` section. I manually update the color in what would be `distr_plot$x$data$[[i]]$line$color` to match what is set in global colors. This will ensure that the colors for each sample do not change.

```
  # plot
  output$distribution_plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(mydata(),selected_variable_plot())
    distr_plot <- plot_distr(data = mydata(), groupby = selected_variable_plot())
    
    distr_plot <- ggplotly(distr_plot)
    
    # Loop through each data item and find the color that is associated with the name
    # then assign that color
    distr_plot$x$data = lapply(distr_plot$x$data, function(x) {
      color = global_colors[which(names(global_colors) %in% x$name)]
      x$line$color = color
      return(x)
    })
    
    return(distr_plot)
  })
```

Example below where you'll see that the colors do not change.

[image: example]